# Web Font height is inconsistent when the text is capitalized

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I'm using VAGRoundedStd-Bold as my font in the navigation.  The navigation is all capitalized.  When it is rendered on the page, the height is consistent.

[screenshot of the navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmXWr.png)

Here is my navigation CSS:

```
.mainNav {
  font-family: VAGRoundedStd-Bold, sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
  transition: max-height 0.8s; }
```

Please let me know what I should change.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this occur without `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still happens when that is removed.